# Where to get package that has the math script font I want?

Tags: fonts, packages, texworks

even though i was aware of TeX for decades, my only use of LaTeX is here on math-oriented StackExchanges or at Wikipedia, and only to edit equations.

so i downloaded TeXworks and the MiKTeX and found, on Overleaf, a sample TeX file that i was able to add an equation to.

here on the math SE, we have a script font `\mathscr{}` that makes the correct script version of "F" for the Fourier Transform:

the font i want is `\mathscr{F}`
[image: mathscr.png]

But what I seem to only be able to get with either Wikipedia or this basic download of TeXworks (and MiKTeX) running on my PC is `\mathcal{F}`
[image]

However invoking `\mathscr{F}` in TeXworks causes an error.  The only packages I am aware I am using (from this Overleaf template) is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
```

I have no idea what else I have to get to get the correct script font `\mathscr{}`

Comment: `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` and `\mathscr{F}`.

Comment: that exactly does it, @egreg.